# Calculate variance

Tags: statistics

I was given this question as HW:

> A survey reveals that on average 1 computer out of 800 computers crashes during a severe
>   thunderstorm. A certain company had 4,000 working computers when the area was hit by
>   a severe thunderstorm. Compute the expected value and variance of the number of crashed
>   computers in the storm.

As far as the expected value goes, I get $\frac{4000}{800}=5$.

But how can I get variance? Are there unstated assumptions that I am missing here? How can I know anything about the distribution just based on the mean?

Comment: The question may be asking you to model using a binomial distribution with $p = 0.00125$ and $n=4000$

Comment: @user130512 how did you get that?

Comment: You may be expected to use the Poisson approximation, variance is $\lambda$. But binomial is better. We are assuming independence, which seems physically unreasonable.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Is the question underspecified, or can I just pick a distribution, defend it, and thats it?

Comment: The question is definitely underspecified

Comment: Call a computer crashing a **success**. Probability $p$ of success is $\frac{1}{800}$, number $n$ of independent (?) trials (computers) is $4000$.

Comment: If one makes the assumption of independence, the problem is fairly well specified. One can poke fun at the independence assumption. We then have a binomial $n$ large $p$ small, $np=5$ medium. Standard setup for using the Poisson approximation to the binomial.

Comment: @soandos; Could they just be expecting npq? $4000 \cdot \frac{ 1}{800} \cdot \frac{799}{800}=\frac{799}{160} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the property of binomial distribution, you can find that the variance for a binomial distribution with mean np (in this case $n = 4000$, $p=1/800$, $q=799/800$) is $npq=4000*(1/800)*(799/800)$